# react dangerouslySetInnerHTML и Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать в связке с React?

У меня есть сторонний api, там обычная страница с блога, данные в виде json. Там есть свои ссылки на внутренние страницы того сайта. Мне нужно выводить у себя статью, а когда переходят по внутренний ссылке, то получать снова json той страницы и отображать новые данные у себя.  В общем, когда гуляют по статьям, то все происходит у меня, просто меняются данные в адресной строке, а к серверу делаются запросы за новыми данными. При этом должна работать навигация в браузере назад и в перед.

Я беру данные, изменяет все ссылка на link, и вывожу всю статью с помощью dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Но вот тут у меня проблема, потому что он не обрабатывает Link. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать? Может я изначально выбрал не правильное направление?

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно из текста, но судя по всему, ты получаешь json, в котором одно из полей — это html, который ты и пихаешь в `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, предварительно заменив  на .

**Никогда так не делай!** Взять html со стороннего ресурса и вставить его в свою страницу — это очень плохая идея. См. что такое [XSS-атака](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Правильное решение в твоем случае — это взять одну из библиотек [вроде этой](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react). Она превратит входной html в React-компонент. В процессе парсинга можно будет заменить иходные  на . Как это сделать [см. доку](https://github.com/aknuds1/html-to-react#with-custom-processing-instructions).